# Closure inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a closure function inside a for loop as following:

```
for (var j = 0; j < end.length; j++) {
    directionsService[iReq] = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService[iReq].route(request[iReq], (function(){
        return function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                legs = response.routes[0].legs;
                for (var iLeg = 0; iLeg < legs.length; iLeg++) {
                    totalDistance += legs[iLeg].distance.value; //Math.floor((legs[iLeg].distance.value)/1000)*100;
                }
            }
            alert("1"); //1
        }
    })());
    alert("2"); //2
}
```

It should alert "1" and "2" respectively, however, I always got alert "2" before "1". What's wrong with my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript wrong alert order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552530/javascript-wrong-alert-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`directionsService[iReq].route` appears to be an asynchronous function --  it lets other code run first, then only when it's ready, then it calls the callback function given *after* other code has run.

Placing your code in an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) does nothing to prevent `alert(2);` from running before `alert(1);`.

Answer (score 0):

your function is a callback, put `alert('2')` inside your funcion, after `alert('1')`, because callback functions can be executed asynchronously